# Financial constraints, stock return and R&D

Tags: asset-pricing

I am doing research on "Financial constraints, stock return and R&D in India". we have constructed the Financial constraints index with the help of Kaplan and Zingles (1997) and Lamont et al. (2001). we find significant positive relation between FC and stock return. R&D is insignificant negatively related with stock returns. but when R&D interact with FC, then this interaction effect has significant negative impact on stock returns. We can explain it as FC increase, the R&D and stock return relation become negative. what could be the possible explanation. How I justify these results? Please help me in understanding these results. Thank you,
regards